# Cannot upgrade from 12.04LTS to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I have been trying to upgrade to 14.04 for several days now, but every time I get this error message:

```
W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_universe_i18n_Translation-en  
Encountered a section with no Package: header, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: you might need to run `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to rebuild the apt cache:

```
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1983220&page=5