# Trouble upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04.1 lts

Tags: upgrade

After running these commands from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

I get the following error message:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources 404 Not Found,
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix this bug?

Comment: which version of 12.04? as support for 12.04.(1-3) has ended

Comment: The error mentions `oneiric`. Are you upgrading from 11.04?

Comment: I bought a dell installed with ubuntu 11.04. Then i upgraded to 12.04 lts. http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources is the error message after running sudo do-release-upgrade

Comment: @sbergeron Is that significant to this situation, though? On an installed system, point releases correspond to package upgrades. Even a 12.04 system installed from a pre-12.04.1 ISO will upgrade (automatically) to the latest point release when updates are installed. The `update` and `dist-upgrade` actions should achieve this if it hasn't already happened, and they're being run before the `do-release-upgrade` command. **Stanley Hlatshwayo**: I recommend editing your question to include the complete output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` (copy, paste, select, Ctrl+K to make it look right).

Comment: @EliahKagan ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main

Comment: @StanleyHlatshwayo Please *edit your **question** itself* to include the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`. It is not appearing correctly as a comment. In particular, it looks like most of it may not have fit into the comment.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to disable any software sources added manually, as this is probably the source of your error message. 
See the following link for more details:
[How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-updating-packages)

If this doesn't work, you can try the following commands to rebuild the cache (As suggested in the link below).

```
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

[Cannot upgrade from 12.04LTS to 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512976/cannot-upgrade-from-12-04lts-to-14-04)

Also, unless you want to try to install the latest devel. version, I would suggest you to drop the "-d" and simply run `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

- Open *Software & Updates*, e.g. via the Dash.
- Select the *Other Software* tab.
- Uncheck the *Independent* item.