# "unresolvable problem" error when upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

So I have solved [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512976/cannot-upgrade-from-12-04lts-to-14-04#), but now I have another problem:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

 This can be caused by:
 * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.
```

I am not upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu and I am not running a pre-release either. I have unchecked all my 3rd-party packages using Ubuntu Software Manager, Edit>Software Sources...

What else might be wrong?

**UPDATE**

After doing `sudo update-manager -d` and `sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` as per JimB's post, and then running `sudo do-release-upgrade`, here what I get:

```
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                                                                                              

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                                                                                           

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                                                                                              

Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                                                                                           
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                                                                                              
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                            

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This can be caused by: 
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
=== Command detached from window (Mon Aug 18 23:53:10 2014) ===
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Mon Aug 18 23:53:10 2014) ===
```

**UPDATE 2**

My /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb apps
```

Comment: The message you've pasted here looks like it is just a general failure message that should come *after* some more specific error messages.  Those error messages will be more helpful in finding the cause of the issue.

Comment: @neon_overload see my update for more details ;)

Comment: Thanks flyingfisch, I saw that change and it looks like you are missing data (and/or have incorrect data) in your /etc/apt/sources.list - if you have access to the GUI you can regenerate this with software sources, select for example the US server.  I don't know the specific answer to your question though which is why I haven't answered.  Perhaps you could post your /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: I changed the software sources, but I still get the same error...

Comment: @neon_overload ok, I updated my post to show sources.list

Comment: Just curious, does it work if you comment out the two lines near the bottom that contain reference to "extras.ubuntu.com"?

Also, do you know of any packages that you've installed that did not come from the official Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: @neon_overload hmm, i know I had a lot of 3rd-party ppas... is there a tool to list all the packages not gotten from the official repos?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for providing all the additional information you have provided so far.

It's strange that Ubuntu doesn't seem to be providing any more helpful information than "Could not calculate the upgrade".  What would be nice is if it told us what packages could not be upgraded.

As part of the release upgrade, Ubuntu does the equivalent of a regular apt-get dist-upgrade, the normal way that it updates packages to new versions.  As part of this it needs to fully check dependencies for all packages it is going to modify, to ensure that, for example, a package is not going to be incompatible with other packages.

Ubuntu will have thoroughly tested the update procedure for all their packages, and ensured that there are upgrade paths for people upgrading.  However where this can fall apart is when you have installed packages from sources other than the official Ubuntu repositories.  Specifically, if these packages are marked as depending on official Ubuntu packages.  This can be the case with packages installed from PPAs or backports, which typically depend on system libraries in Ubuntu.  If you try to upgrade Ubuntu without upgrading these packages at the same time, those packages may continue to depend on previous versions of important system libraries, making a full scale upgrade of Ubuntu impossible.

Steps to take:

- For any package installed from outside the official repositories (including packages installed from PPAs), make sure the source you installed them from is still included in your software sources and that source also includes a version of the package compatible with the newer version of Ubuntu.
- For any packages installed from outside official repositories where the original source is no longer in your software sources, or where they don't provide a version of the package compatible with the new version of Ubuntu, uninstall those packages prior to upgrade of Ubuntu.

Comment: How can I find all the packages that are installed outside the official repos?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, but [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5976/how-can-i-list-all-packages-ive-installed-from-a-particular-ppa) answer should work - it's GUI based not command line though.

Comment: some PPA's I have are only updates to packages that were in the official repos. Should I remove these packages? Some of them are things like graphics drivers...

Answer (score 0):

try running

`sudo update-manager -d`

or if you've started the update already and things broke down it's likely ubuntu already disabled all the repos that are giving you issues so do

`sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

good luck!

Comment: that didn't fix it, I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: I don't suppose that update-manager command gave any more info about which packages caused the failure to "calculate the upgrade"?  I'm guessing no but I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the upgrade fails, some information may be found in `/var/log/dist-upgrade`.
2. To reproduce the errors visibly: make a copy of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and edit the file replacing old repositories with new ones. Do:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -s
   ```

   This will do an upgrade dry run and print out any errors.

   Broken update-dependencies can be resolved by `apt-get remove`ing the offending packages.

   Finally copy the original version of `sources.list` back and run `update-manager` again.